# Changing the direction of a css arrow

Tags: html, css

I have gotten a css animation arrow the is pointed left to right and it works as expected- the animation also works fine. I am trying to change the direction of this arrow so that is points from right to left. I have tried to change the before and after elements but this does not seem to change the direction of the arrow?

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.the-arrow {
  width: 64px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.the-arrow.-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 0;
}

.the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 0;
  background-color: #999;
}

.the-arrow.-left .shaft:before,
.the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  width: 0;
  background-color: #999;
}

.the-arrow.-left .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.the-arrow.-right {
  top: 3px;
}

.the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 64px;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.the-arrow.-right .shaft:before,
.the-arrow.-right>.shaft:after {
  width: 8px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.the-arrow.-right .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

.the-arrow .shaft {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0;
  will-change: transform;
}

.the-arrow .shaft:before,
.the-arrow .shaft:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

.the-arrow .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.the-arrow .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.animated-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.animated-arrow:hover {
  color: #eaeaea;
}

.animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft {
  width: 64px;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before,
.animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  width: 8px;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.animated-arrow:hover .the-arrow.-left .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

.animated-arrow:hover .main {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
  transform: translateX(80px);
}

.animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-right .shaft {
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
  transform: translateX(200%);
  transition-delay: 0;
}

.animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-right .shaft:before,
.animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  width: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-right .shaft:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.animated-arrow:hover .main .the-arrow.-right .shaft:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.animated-arrow .main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.animated-arrow .main .text {
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.animated-arrow .main .the-arrow {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="pivot-arrows-1" style="">


  <a class="animated-arrow arrow-c-f" href="#">
    <span class="the-arrow -left">
      <span class="shaft"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="main">
      <span class="text">
        Link Text
      </span>
    <span class="the-arrow -right">
        <span class="shaft"></span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I did not understand which one you want to rotate but you can apply a rotation to the whole element

```
.the-arrow.-left {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.the-arrow.-right {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

If you want rotate the arrow in general just

```
.the-arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: I want to change the direction so that  the arrow is pointing right to left

Comment: So it should be enough rotating the ".the-arrow" elements

Comment: that works to rotate the arrow. Thanks What about moving the text to the right of the arrow now?